# How to use Visual Studio JavaScript editor to name a variable by its scientific symbol, e.g. Ω, the Greek large letter Omega

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, unicode, editor, symbols

I want to use the Visual Studio JavaScript editor to name variables by their corresponding scientific symbols. In VS2013 update 5 I can view code written this way, but I do not know how to write code this way. `var cosφ0 = Math.cos(φ0)`